# Media Player support for Web Assembly in UNO

Tags: media-player, webassembly, uno-platform

I was developing an APP on UNO for playing Videos. It works fine on other platforms except for WASM. I checked the code and realized that `MediaPlayerElement` is not implemented for Web Assembly.

Is there any workaround for that available currently or is it a work in progress and will be available soon, or Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

For playing media on an Uno Platform WebAssembly app you can look at the [`HtmlMediaPlayer` implementation](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Ch9/blob/master/src/Ch9/Ch9.Wasm/HtmlMediaPlayer.cs) in the [Ch9 app](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Ch9). The full code is below.

There's a couple of points to note:

- The `HtmlElement` attribute tells Uno to create a `<video/>` tag as the underlying DOM element for this control
- The `OnSourceChanged()` callback passes the `Source` to the native `<video/>` by using the [`ExecuteJavascript()` extension method](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/79a3444aee0669b5d825b41262c8d2c00121f54f/src/Uno.UI.Runtime.WebAssembly/Xaml/UIElementWasmExtensions.cs#L119) from Uno.

```cs
    [HtmlElement("video")]
    public sealed partial class HtmlMediaPlayer : Border
    {
        public HtmlMediaPlayer()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Source", typeof(string), typeof(HtmlMediaPlayer), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnSourceChanged));

        public string Source
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static async void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject dependencyobject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (dependencyobject is HtmlMediaPlayer player)
            {
                var encodedSource = WebAssemblyRuntime.EscapeJs("" + args.NewValue);
                var js = $"element.controls = true; element.src=\"{encodedSource}\";";
                player.ExecuteJavascript(js);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see in Ch9 how this is used as a drop-in replacement for `MediaPlayerElement`:

```xml
            <not_wasm:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                                         Source="{Binding VideoSource}"
                                         IsFullWindow="{Binding Parent.IsVideoFullWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Height="180" />
            <wasm:Border>
                <localwasm:HtmlMediaPlayer x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                                           Height="180"
                                           Source="{Binding VideoUri}" />
            </wasm:Border>
```

Proper `MediaPlayerElement` support will likely be added to Uno Platform in the future, you can help prioritize it by [upvoting the issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/899).

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for quick reply. I tried Channel 9 HtmlMediaPlayer by getting CH9 app from GitHub. Unfortunately I am getting error  "Something Went Wrong. Please try again" only on wasm. Could I be missing some installs/dependencies etc.

Comment: The output in the console window may give you more clues as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Looks like security issue, getting CORS error                                                                                              Access to fetch at 'https://ch9-app.azurewebsites.net/api/proxy?url=https://s.ch9.ms/feeds/rss' from origin 'http://localhost:59591' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.                                                       How can I enable this?

Comment: @AmitVerma You should probably create a new question for the CORS issue, specifying the error details, source configuration etc.